# Configure wildcard A records for sub domains

Tags: dns, domain-name, wildcards

So, I have a zone file for a certain domain, in json, a part of it looks like so:

```
"a": [
    { "name": "@", "ttl": 400, "value": "10.24.54.1" },
    { "name": "@", "ttl": 400, "value": "172.14.2.41" },
    { "name": "@", "ttl": 400, "value": "192.14.2.41" }
    { "name": "@", "ttl": 400, "value": "10.10.10.10" }
]
```

So, if anyone queries for `*.domain.com` they would get the same IP.

I'd be grateful if someone could suggest how to change this to match every sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a Jon zone file, so I'm unclear what software you are using, but change the "@" to "*" (or add "additional entries with *)

@ implies the domain origin, while * implies all subdomain not explicitly listed.